# Spring WebFlux create pool of no-blocking threads

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I decided to rewrite my web app on Java(previously it was on Python).
In my app I used no-blocking I/O, I had worker pool(Celery + Eventlet threads) where I pass tasks which consists of hundreds of API calls.

Now I'm using **Spring WebFlux** but I can't understand how I can create a workers pool to pass my tasks to that pool, and after get results and do some calculations.

(I know about possibility to create ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, but the threads are blocking threads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using non-blocking APIs, you don't need to schedule tasks on specific threads - Reactor is doing that for you. With Spring WebFlux, the threads used for processing work are managed by Reactor or it is reusing the Netty threads.

Check out the [Schedulers and threading parts of the reactor reference documentation](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers).

Comment: Brian, could you help me? Let assume(for the sake of briefness)I do 600 API calls for each incoming user request in controller, they are really similar to each other, after that I need to get result of execution and do some calculations and only after that I return result. 1) How can I make such similar requests by whole group and get result(Flux) by whole group (kind of stream API)? 2) If I make such big request for each controller without using pool of workers, and ask for result right inside controller, will it make reactor to pass the task in the same internal execution pool?