# Spring WebFlux & WebClient make many API calls

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

Recently I asked question [Spring WebFlux create pool of no-blocking threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012749/spring-webflux-create-pool-of-no-blocking-threads)

I got the answer, read link provided, but still don't understand the right way of doing such stuff.

I use **Spring WebFlux (WebClient)** to write my REST service. For each incoming request I make several hundred requests to another REST service, so to make them as fast as possible I want to use no-blocking threads.

Let I got request from client and I have to make 600 API calls:

`List<String> urls = Arrays.asList("www.example-rest.com/url1", "www.example-rest.com/url2", ..., "www.example-rest.com/url600");`

- I want to make them in parallel way and using no-blocking threads (like eventlet in Python)
- I want to create separate shared worker pool with such threads in order not to make one for each incoming request.

Here is the documentation about **schedulers**
http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers

I found there information about **elastic thread pool**:

> An **elastic thread pool** (Schedulers.elastic()). It creates new worker
>   pools as needed, and reuse idle ones. This is a good choice for I/O
>   blocking work for instance. Schedulers.elastic() is a handy way to
>   give a blocking process its own thread, so that it does not tie up
>   other resources.

But I can't create new worker pool for each request, and thread inside that pool still works in blocking way.

If anybody did similar task with **Spring WebClient** please provide an example, explain what is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar...  My goal was to create a method with a signature like this:

```
Flux<BasicIssue> getIssues(WebClient webClient);
```

Because the website I was calling provided only a paged interface, I needed to feed the results of multiple REST calls into a single Flux.  Below is my implementation.  Please note my use of CachedThreadPool.

```
Flux<BasicIssue> getIssues(WebClient webClient) {
    return Flux.generate(
        () -> new IssuesState(webClient),
        (state, sink) -> {
            BasicIssue ret = state.getNext();
            if (ret == null) {
                sink.complete();
            } else {
                sink.next(ret);
            }
            return state;
        }
}


class IssuesState {

    private final AtomicBoolean isDone = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final AtomicInteger threadCount = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private final LinkedBlockingQueue<BasicIssue> issueQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

    public IssuesState(WebClient webClient) {
        executor.execute(() -> getNextBlock(webClient, 0));
    }

    private void getNextBlock(final WebClient webClient, final int startAt) {
        webClient
            .get()
            .uri(...)
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Utils.encodeToString(("username:password".getBytes(UTF_8))))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(PageableIssue.class)
            .subscribe(pageableIssue -> {
                int maxResults = pageableIssue.getMaxResults();
                int total = pageableIssue.getTotal();
                if (startAt == 0) {
                    for (int i = startAt + maxResults; i < total; i += maxResults) {
                        threadCount.incrementAndGet();
                        final int x = i;
                        executor.execute(() -> getNextBlock(webClient, x));
                    }
                }
                synchronized (issueQueue) {
                    for (BasicIssue issue : pageableIssue.getIssues()) {
                        issueQueue.add(issue);
                    }

                    if (threadCount.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                        isDone.set(true);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    public BasicIssue getNext() {
        synchronized (issueQueue) {
            if (isDone.get() && issueQueue.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        try {
            return issueQueue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using the above method..

```
getIssues(webClient)
    .subscribe(basicIssue -> System.out.println(basicIssue.getName());
```